# Implement a Shape abstract class

Tags: java, beginner, inheritance

To learn more about OOP, @nhgrif challenged me to implement a Shape abstract class (more details in code remarks below. Here is how I did it. Any and all advice appreciated!

#### Shape.java

```
/* nhgrif says:
 * Phrancis ready for inheritance/polymorphism?
 * Given the following abstract class:
 *
 *  public abstract class Shape {
 *      public abstract double area();
 *      public abstract double perimeter();
 *  }
 *
 * Implement a Circle, Triangle, and Rectangle class which extend the class Shape.
 * Ex: public class Circle extends Shape ... etc
 */

public abstract class Shape {
    public abstract double area();
    public abstract double perimeter();
}
```

#### Rectangle.java

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape {
    private final double width, length; //sides

    public Rectangle() {
        this(1,1);
    }
    public Rectangle(double width, double length) {
        this.width = width;
        this.length = length;
    }

    @Override
    public double area() {
        // A = w * l
        return width * length;
    }

    @Override
    public double perimeter() {
        // P = 2(w + l)
        return 2 * (width + length);
    }

}
```

#### Circle.java

```
public class Circle extends Shape {
    private final double radius;
    final double pi = Math.PI;

    public Circle() {
        this(1);
    }   
    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    public double area() {
        // A = π r^2
        return pi * Math.pow(radius, 2);
    }

    public double perimeter() {
        // P = 2πr
        return 2 * pi * radius;
    }
}
```

#### Triangle.java

```
public class Triangle extends Shape {
    private final double a, b, c; // sides

    public Triangle() {
        this(1,1,1);
    }
    public Triangle(double a, double b, double c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public double area() {
        // Heron's formula:
        // A = SquareRoot(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)) 
        // where s = (a + b + c) / 2, or 1/2 of the perimeter of the triangle 
        double s = (a + b + c) / 2;
        return Math.sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
    }

    @Override
    public double perimeter() {
        // P = a + b + c
        return a + b + c;
    }
}
```

And this is what I used to test it all, which it all works as intended:

#### TestShape.java

```
public class TestShape {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Rectangle test
        double width = 5, length = 7;
        Shape rectangle = new Rectangle(width, length);
        System.out.println("Rectangle width: " + width + " and length: " + length
                + "\nResulting area: " + rectangle.area()
                + "\nResulting perimeter: " + rectangle.perimeter() + "\n");

        // Circle test
        double radius = 5;
        Shape circle = new Circle(radius);
        System.out.println("Circle radius: " + radius
            + "\nResulting Area: " + circle.area()
            + "\nResulting Perimeter: " + circle.perimeter() + "\n");

        // Triangle test
        double a = 5, b = 3, c = 4;
        Shape triangle = new Triangle(a,b,c);
        System.out.println("Triangle sides lengths: " + a + ", " + b + ", " + c
                + "\nResulting Area: " + triangle.area()
                + "\nResulting Perimeter: " + triangle.perimeter() + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Now do the tricky ones: ellipse and square. <g>

Comment: Well square could just extend Rectangle. Ellipse would be interesting for sure though.

Comment: @Legato - or rectangle could extend square.

Comment: @PeteBecker Not every rectangle is a square.

Comment: @Legato - sometimes. Not always.

Comment: Yes, and rectangle extending square would imply always.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21825/discussion-between-legato-and-pete-becker).

Comment: On your `Circle.java`, you forgot an `@Override` on the `perimeter()` method.

Comment: A square should never extend a rectangle, or vice versa.  This is a direct infraction of the Liskov Substitution Principle and could lead to unexpected side effects.

Comment: @DarrenYoung Isn't a square a rectangle?

Comment: @PeteBecker Square extending Rectangle is only allowed if they are immutable.  The other way around is not allowed.

Comment: I love the neatness of the code, just a thought/doubt since ```Rectangle``` ```Circle``` ```Triangle``` is a ```Shape``` and they all have sides, so should sides not be part of ```Shape``` itself.

Comment: A `Circle` has an infinite number of sides. Think about it. So how would `Shape` represent the sides of a circle?

Comment: Looks a lot like https://github.com/adsouza/Euclidean-Geometry/tree/master/Java

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am generally impressed with the consistency of the implementations, neatness, etc.

I have a comment about the basic premise. The `Shape` should not be an abstract class, but an interface. It has no concrete implementations for any methods, and making it an abstract class makes it hard to inherit from other places too. Consider this instead:

```
public interface Shape {
    public double area();
    public double perimeter();
}
```

In addition to that concern, the following are also things you should consider:

- The `pi` field on your `Circle` class should be private. There's no need to re-expose an already public constant in another way.
- I would avoid the 'unit' default constructors. They don't help with anything. When would someone want to call `new Triangle()` and not want to have the dimensions?
- Your classes are missing a `toString()` method. These are useful for many reasons, especially debugging.
- You don't have a plan for out-of-bound dimensions. What will you do with negative, NaN, or infinite input?

Comment: I would even suggest to not have a `pi` field and use `Math.PI` directly. Or do a `import static java.lang.Math.PI;` and use `PI` directly

Comment: `interface` methods are `public` by default. (one of my pet peeves are redundant modifiers - Java is already verbose enough).

Comment: @BoristheSpider - yeah, they are public by default, I understand your concern, and you're right that it should be pointed out. As it happens, I learned Java while at a job where the code style guidelines required it, and it's a habit I have kept, and I now prefer making it explicit. I'm not claiming I'm right, but I am claiming that it would not be *'my'* answer if I edited it out ;-)

Answer (score 12):

A nitpick on names: The dimensions of a rectangle should be `width` and `height` not `width` and `length`. The constructor of Triangle should take descriptive parameter names, such as `side1Length`. You have more excuse to use `a` and `b` for private fields (especially in this short, pure math code), but single-character names are generally frowned upon.

Add javadoc comments, at least to the methods in your abstract class/interface. The comment to your `Shape` class is almost a javadoc, but it is missing one `*`.

For extra credit, replace your `main()` method with 3 unit tests (1 test class with 3 methods) that can be easily run from the IDE.

Comment: I would suggest a unit test class for _each_ implementation - this is the accepted standard approach. Other than that, all very good points.

Comment: @BoristheSpider You're right, but personally I would not stick firmly to this rule in such a trivial case, preferring to reduce the number of test classes and make test code reuse a simple matter of a private method `testShape(Shape shape, double expectedArea, double expectedPerimiter)` in `class ShapeTest` rather than build an inheritance heirarchy for it.

Answer (score 7):

I'm glad you did this, gives me a chance to further enforce/correct some misinformation.

`final double pi = Math.PI;` this is a circumstance where the value pi should be *static* and would appropriately be written as UPPERCASE `PI`.

- Static since the value of pi is not dependent on any instance of Circle
- Final, since of course you wouldn't want anything changing it
- Uppercase since it is both these things, it is considered **constant** thus the naming convention.

Though, there's no need for you to take up namespace or memory when you can *directly use* `Math.PI`. For instance, your `double area()` method's implementation could be:

`return Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);`

For the same reason instead of having placeholder variables that aren't used elsewhere:

```
double a = 5, b = 3, c = 4;
Shape triangle = new Triangle(a,b,c);
```

Simply use them

```
Shape triangle = new Triangle(5, 3, 4);
```

a, b, and c aren't really fitting names to begin with, if you do elect to use them try using more descriptive names such as base, side1, and side2 in this case.

I like that you use the abstract class to declare in your tests, doing that will afford you some flexibility in the future, just make sure you understand that when you rely on specific methods that only exist in a subclass you'd have to declare with that subclass.

Comment: The placeholder variables increase readability.

Comment: I disagree that a, b and c are not good names. While using several consecutive single-letter names for fields would usually be a code smell, in this case they are appropriate. They are the standard names for the three sides of a triangle and are ubiquitous in triangle geometry. Calling them base, side1 and side2 falsely suggests that the three have distinct meanings.

Answer (score 6):

One minor nitpick, really:

```
// where s = (a + b + c) / 2, or 1/2 of the perimeter of the triangle 
double s = (a + b + c) / 2;
```

In the comment you refer to the perimeter of the triangle, but in your code you don't use the actual perimeter. This is very small code duplication. Your code would be a bit more self-documenting if you would do:

```
double s = perimeter() / 2;
```

---

I personally have nothing against the a, b, c names in this case. The sides are often named that in Mathematics, I don't think it's horribly wrong to name them that here as well.

Comment: This is a minor point but a very good one.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I think the default no-arg constructor is very unnecessary if these are immutable classes. Does a Rectangle by default having width 1 and height 1 make much sense?

And also, if the classes are immutable, you might as well calculate the areas and perimeters right away, so they can be just returned in the appropriate methods.

I also think the naming of methods could be better. Instead of `area()` I would use `getArea()`.

The modified Rectangle would look like the following (note that the Shape class would also need to be edited):

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape {
  private final double width, height, area, perimeter;

  public Rectangle(double width, double height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height= height;
    this.area = width * height;
    this.perimeter = 2 * (width + height);
  }

  @Override
  public double getArea() {
    return this.area;
  }

  @Override
  public double getPerimeter() {
    return this.perimeter;
  }

}
```

Comment: `getX` is usually a sign that the method returns a predefined value. Which is the case here but makes it inappropriate for his implementation. I don't really see an issue with the name, but if he had to change it I'd probably choose `computeX`

Comment: Right.. Or maybe `calculateArea()`?

Comment: Works just as well.

Comment: From *Effective Java*: `Methods that return a non-boolean function or attribute of the object on which they’re invoked are usually named with a noun, a noun phrase, or a verb phrase beginning with the verb get, for example, size, hashCode, or getTime. There is a vocal contingent that claims that only the third form (beginning with get) is acceptable, but there is little basis for this claim. The first two forms usually lead to more readable code.` A value class with few non-getter methods may use a noun like `area()`. `calculateArea` suggest the function has side-effects or is noticeably slow.